# How do i get unsplit text result after a certain text split

Tags: php, string, split

I have this code below

```
$txt = "12345678910";

$start = preg_split("/5/", $txt); 

$split = str_split($start[1], 2);

echo implode(',', $split);

echo $start[0];
```

Which start text split from 5 example 67, 89, 10  in my achievement, I want to be able get the let unsplit text and the split text also example my result show look like:
`67, 89, 10` and
`12345`
 thanks for understanding and impact in my soluction.

Comment: $start[0] will return 1234

Comment: Oh i wish to get 12345 in result i have that oready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, It'll work as per your requirement. :) I just used `explode()` instead of first `preg_split()`

```
$num = 5;
$txt = "12345678910";
$length = strlen($txt);
$initial = substr($txt, 0, $num);
$explode = explode($num, $txt); 
$result = str_split($explode[1], 2);
array_push($result,$initial);
echo implode(',', $result);
```

**Edit:** As per comment

```
$num = 5;
$array_var = [];
$txt = "12345678910";
$length = strlen($txt);
$initial = substr($txt, 0, $num);
$explode = explode($num, $txt); 
$result = str_split($explode[1], 2);
$array_var[] = implode(',',$result);
$array_var[] = $initial;
list($firstvar, $secondvar) = $array_var;
echo "First variable = $firstvar and Second variable $secondvar";
```

Comment: Nice idea but not as was just expecting $start[0]+1 inform

Comment: Thanks @Being sunny but can i get each result in variables example 
   $firstvar  = 67, 89, 10
   $secondvar = 12345

Comment: @Et'zGodknowsPeters, Yes of course, I am updating my answer

Comment: @Et'zGodknowsPeters, Check my updated answer and let me know whether it works for you now?

Answer (score 0):

save the split char to a variable and access it like this

```
<?php
$txt = "12345678910";

$splitOn = 5;
$start = preg_split("/$splitOn/", $txt); 

$split = str_split($start[1], 2);

echo implode(',', $split);

echo "\n";

echo $start[0].$splitOn;

?>
```